# How to get a confusion matrix plotted with modified output size and output as .svg image in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, seaborn, confusion-matrix

I want to plot a confusion matrix as I have two matrices namely y_test_ and y_pred. I want the output image as ".svg". And as I have to put the image on my project report I want its size to be modifiable. I want to be able to modify the image size as my paper requires.

I have already tried the "confusion_matrix" function from "sklearn.metrics". But the output image is way too small than I need. Moreover, the image is in ".png" format. The code I used is given below.

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

def plot_confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, classes, normalize=False, title=None, cmap=plt.cm.Blues):
    if not title:
        if normalize:
            title = 'Normalized confusion matrix'
        else:
            title = 'Confusion matrix, without normalization'

    cm = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)

    if normalize:
        cm = cm.astype('float') / cm.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
        print("Normalized confusion matrix")
    else:
        print('Confusion matrix, without normalization')

    print(cm)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    im = ax.imshow(cm, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap)

    ax.figure.colorbar(im, ax=ax)
    ax.set(xticks=np.arange(cm.shape[1]), yticks=np.arange(cm.shape[0]), xticklabels=classes, yticklabels=classes, title=title, 
           ylabel='True label',
           xlabel='Predicted label')

    plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha="right", rotation_mode="anchor")

    fmt = '.2f' if normalize else 'd'
    thresh = cm.max() / 2.

    for i in range(cm.shape[0]):
        for j in range(cm.shape[1]):
            ax.text(j, i, format(cm[i, j], fmt),
                    ha="center", va="center",
                    color="white" if cm[i, j] > thresh else "black")

    fig.tight_layout()
    return ax

plot_confusion_matrix(y_test_, y_pred, classes=class_names, title='Confusion matrix, without normalization')
plot_confusion_matrix(y_test_, y_pred, classes=class_names, normalize=True, title='Normalized confusion matrix')

plt.show()
```

This code generates the image that is not clear to put on a paper and is not in the form ".svg". Suggest me what to do.

Answer (score 2):

**For clear Output**

You have not provided full code but, I think if you are using seaborn you can use `sns.set()` as follows

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sn
sn.set()
%matplotlib inline
```

**For saving the file as .svg use** following before calling `plt.show()`

```
plt.savefig("test.svg", format="svg")
```

OR

```
plt.savefig("test.svg")
```